# Get specific classes n-grams

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram, vocabulary, countvectorizer

I have a dataset of tweets, each labeled as *hate* (1) or *non hate* (0). I vectorized the data using a *[3,4] character n-grams* bag of words (sklearn's *CountVectorizer*) and I want to extract the most frequent n-grams for **each class**. The following code works but it generalizes to the whole data instead of focusing on the classes themselves.

```
bag_of_words = CountVectorizer(
    ngram_range =(3,4),
    analyzer='char'
)

bag_of_words_mx = bag_of_words.fit_transform(X)

vocab = bag_of_words.vocabulary_
count_values = bag_of_words_mx.toarray().sum(axis=0)

# output n-grams
for ng_count, ng_text in sorted([(count_values[i],k) for k,i in vocab.items()]):
    if ng_count > 1:
        print(ng_count, ng_text)
```

Is there a way to somehow sort the vocabulary by class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bag_of_words_mx[y == 0]` and `bag_of_words_mx[y == 1]`, where `y` is the array containing your target variable.